# In the world of ZFC + Grothendieck universes, is there a standard model for ZFC?

Tags: set-theory

Consider the set of ZFC axioms extended with the following [axiom of universes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+universe#axiom_of_universes):

> For every set $s$, there exists a [Grothendieck universe](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+universe#definition) $U$ that contains $s$, i.e. $s \in U$.

1. Is it possible to prove that, for every set $s$ there is a minimal universe $U_m$ containing $s$, such that $U_m$ is contained in every other universe $U$ that contains $s$?
2. If the answer to the previous question is, in general, "no", can it at least be shown for the particular case that $s$ is the set of natural numbers?
3. If the answer to the previous question is "no", is there a set in the world of ZFC + the axiom of universes that can be considered standard by any other reason, in other words, can we identify, on intrinsic grounds rather than arbitrarily, a particular set $V$ which merits being called "THE class of ZFC sets"?

* If feasible, please try not to involve category theory in your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Grothendieck universe is the same thing as a set of the form $V_\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal.  So, given any set $s$, there is a smallest Grothendieck universe, namely $V_\kappa$ for the least inaccessible cardinal greater than the rank of $s$.

Alternatively, it is immediate from the definition of a Grothendieck universe that any intersection of Grothendieck universes is a Grothendieck universe, so just take the intersection of all Grothendieck universes containing $s$.

That said, the smallest Grothendieck universe is pretty much never considered to be the "standard model" of ZFC.  Why should it be?  For instance, if you accept the axiom of universes, why shouldn't you think that the "standard model" ought to have inaccessible cardinals?

Comment: But is the intersection of all the Grothendieck universes containing some $s$ definable in ZFC + the axiom of universes?

Comment: Yes, the intersection of any nonempty class of sets is a set, by Separation (applied to any element of the class).

Comment: And how do you obtain, to begin with, the set of all Grothendieck universes containing a given $s$? What do you separate it *from*?

Comment: Pick one Grothendieck universe $U$ containing $s$, and take the subset consisting of all elements of $U$ that are in every Grothendieck universe containing $s$.

Comment: Regarding your question: "if you accept the axiom of universes, why shouldn't you think that the "standard model" ought to have inaccessible cardinals?" the reason is that after more than a hundred years during which the axioms of ZFC were considered to define the foundations of all of mathematics, you might be interested in investigating, or, at least identifying, in your new foundations the object that constitutes the "old world".

Comment: @EvanAad ZFC is not the same thing as ZFC + there are no inaccessible cardinals. (Or at least it isn't provided inaccessibles are consistent.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: This is true, but in my experience it is common practice in mathematics, once you identify a certain list of properties to be interested in the minimal collection of elements that satisfy these properties, and if such exists, and if it is not trivial (i.e. the empty set, or a singleton), it is usually considered the standard model of the list of properties. There is also of course the dual approach, that coexists with the former one, of considering all the objects that satisfy the list of properties, and see what they have in common.